# Convert from BindingSource to Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms

convert ComboBox.DataSource from BindingSource to Dictionary<String, Tuple<double, string, string>>

```
        public static Tuple<double, string, string> SelectCurrencyFromComboBox( ComboBox combobox, Guid guid )
        {
            BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)combobox.DataSource);

          //  Dictionary<String, Tuple<double, string, string>> ds = bs.Cast<BindingSource>().ToDictionary()
            return (Tuple<double, string, string>)( (Dictionary<String, Tuple<double, string, string>>)bs ).Select( i => i.Value ).Where( a => Guid.Parse( a.Item2 ) == guid );
        }
```

when call method
Error

Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Tuple<double, string, string>>'

Comment: To convert a `BindingSource` to a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, string, string>>`, you need to extract the data from the `BindingSource` and then create a dictionary from it.

Comment: Why would you do that? What is the DataSource of the BindingSource?